# Are there any pitfalls to var something = something || {}

Tags: javascript, syntax

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174172/benefits-of-javascript-anonymous-function-with-namespaces/8174220#8174220) where the poster suggested that the shorthand for

```
if(typeof MyNamespace === 'undefined'){
    var MyNamespace = {};
}
```

is

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};
```

Would veteran programmers recommend the latter to simplify the code, or does it overly complicate things, like abusing `++` or `--` in complex compound statements?

---

**EDIT** The reason I asked is b/c a while back someone inspired me by pointing out that a lot of the people who think they are expert programmers make a lot of beginners mistakes. The case at the time was

```
if (isReady){
  //Do Something
}
```

And what he was saying is that a condition should mean something, `isReady` doesn't 'mean' anything, instead, we should use

```
if (isReady === true){
  //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I strongly disagree that `if (isReady === true)` is preferable to `if (isReady)`. The latter is shorter, more readable and its meaning is perfectly clear. It could only be a problem if `isReady` is not a Boolean and the author is not aware of the type coercion that happens in that case.

Comment: @TimDown I should not have used `isReady`, the issue was checking to see if properties/parameters had been defined yet. The argument was that it might have been defined to `false`, which would have failed the conditional, and 2 months down the road lead to a debugging nightmare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stylistically it's fine and safe if what you're defining is a namespace object, but be careful before using it more widely.

It won't only override the value if it is undefined but also when it is `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `null`, or `""`.

In some older buggy browsers, it clobbered an older variable declaration regardless of whether it was a truthy value or not if that variable declaration was in a different `<script>` element.  Sorry, I don't remember which off the top of my head.

Comment: I'll stay away from it then, I don't like using too many of these shortcuts.

Comment: @puk, In JavaScript, shortcuts often mean shipping less code which is a good thing all else being equal.  If you and your maintainers are likely to understand the code a few months from now, then I'd say go for it.  You could always do an experiment.  Put an entry on your calendar for a month from now that says "If you know what (<Javascript-code>) means, feel free to use it from now on" so it'll pop up after you've forgotten this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

`var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};`

is fine. It's a style choice really. I prefer `||`.

Normally `MyNamespace` would throw a reference error because it does not exist but it works in a `var` statement.